# How to select files with numbered extensions from a folder?

Tags: python, listdir

I am trying to build my own dataset for a project. Therefore I need to select  files that have been exported from another program and come with numbered extensions:

```
exported_file_1_aaa.001
exported_file_2_aaa.002
exported_file_3_aaa.003
...
exported_file_5_zzz.925
...and so on.
```

I know how to select files with a specific extension e.g. '.txt' from a folder and append it to a list or dict. Is there any way to solve this with '.nnn'

```
ext = '.nnn'
all_files = [i for i in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.splitext(i)[1] == ext]
for f in all_files:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can mix the capabilities of shell globbing (`glob`) and regex (`re`).

With `glob` you can get the files ending with a number, so that we get a limited number files for `re` to do the final check:

```
glob.iglob('exported_file_*.*[0-9]')
```

Then we can match the files precisely with Regex pattern:

```
\.\d+$
```

this will match file names ending in digits after last `.`.

Putting together:

```
import glob
import re
[file for file in glob.iglob('exported_file_*.*[0-9]') if re.search(r'\.\d+$', file)]
```

---

Shell globbing is not as flexible as `re`, otherwise we could have done with `glob` alone.

Also, if you're sure that all files end in a certain number of digits then `glob` alone would work e.g. for files ending in 3 digits after last `.`:

```
glob.iglob('exported_file_*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! I'm new to python (as you've probably figured) and I really do appreciate the community!

It worked with:
[file for file in glob.iglob('*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]')]

[file for file in glob.iglob('*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]') if re.search(r'\.\+$')] 
gave me the error message 
"search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'"
so I guess I have to pass ", file" as in
[file for file in glob.iglob('*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]') if re.search(r'\.\+$', file)], right?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the length of the extension, you can use the [isdigit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method:

```
all_files = [i for i in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.splitext(i)[1].isdigit()]
for f in all_files: 
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `glob` module.

```
import glob

my_dir = "mydir"

all_files = [fn for fn in glob.glob(f"{my_dir}/*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]")]
```